# Нашел ошибку при прокрутке страницы проверки низкокачественных сообщений

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Найдена ошибка:

[image: скриншот рабочих кнопок]

как видно на этом снимке, кнопки активны и работают, но стоит прокрутить вниз:

[image: скриншот нерабочих кнопок]

и мы видим, что поле текста ответа перекрывает надпись кнопки `Выглядит нормально`, причём кнопки этого ряда не работают.

Comment: Они в [курсе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344041/260198) уже как месяц (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, я вот тоже заметил - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10234/Проблема-при-скроллинге-первых-вопросов, проблема та же, или другая?)

Comment: @Andrew тоже самое. Причина одна (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica как я понял, я далеко не первый, но исправлять пока не торопятся?

Comment: Привыкайте. Скорость фикса багов тут не очень хорошая. Если они не критичные, конечно.