# Проблема при прокрутке первых вопросов

Tags: дефект

При редактировании вопроса получаю такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при достижении верха страницы выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно подобная [проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10233/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: Уже почти месяц знают об [этом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344041/339911)

Comment: Я думаю лучше лишний раз напомнить чем будет висеть неизвестный баг)))